# Is it possible to have a registry script to install keys to 32 and 64 bit locations?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm wondering if I have the ability to have a .reg file install keys to both the 32bit and 64bit locations in the registry??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\FOO]
"FOO"="BAR"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\FOO]
"FOO"="BAR"
```

the first sets the 64Bit value and the 2nd sets the 32Bit value. Change it to what ever you want to insert.

Comment: When I double click on the .reg file, it installs all the keys into WOW6432Node hive. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: run the 64Bit regedit.exe from C:\Windows\sysnative (only visible from 32Bit file manager)